# Split string at specific character but ignore some cases C# LINQ

Tags: string, linq, split

I would need to split a string by comma but to ignore certain cases.

For example this string (after each comma is a space character):

**my word 1, my word 2, my word 3, "my word x, my word y, my word z", my word 4, my word 5**

should be split so that will display:

**my word 1**

**my word 2**

**my word 3**

**"my word x, my word y, my word z"**

**my word 4**

**my word 5**

Basically all words should be split after the comma, except the ones that are in double quotes should be shown as they are with the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string text = @"my word 1, my word 2, ""my word x, my word y"", my word 3";
string pattern = @"[^,""]+|""([^""]*)""";
IEnumerable<string> result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Cast<Match>()
                                  .Select(m => m.Value.Trim())
                                  .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
```

Result:

```
my word 1     
my word 2    
"my word x, my word y"    
my word 3
```